# Powershell get file from server using NTLM auth

Tags: powershell, ntlm

I'm trying to get CSV file from a server with given url. Server with this file has NTLM authorization, and each time I try to use below code I get:

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

```
$source = "http://sql-001.contoso.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?test:Format=CSV&rs:Command=Render"
$destination = "C:\test.csv"
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","p@ssw0rd")
$credCache.Add($source, "Basic", $creds)
$wc.Credentials = $credCache
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `NTLM`, that's what you should specify instead of `Basic`:

```
$credCache.Add($source, "NTLM", $creds)
```

Also you might need to specify the domain:

```
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "p@ssw0rd", "MYDOMAIN")
```

Comment: Thx for answer, but I still get in the powershell console:
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
I'm 100% sure that user and pass are correct, and server use NTLM
Any other ideas?